# Should I test in both 32 and 64 bit in Selenium

Tags: selenium

I have two question regarding Selenium

1.
Is it nessesary to test in the same browser in both 32 and 64 bit?

2.
If I set up Grid, can I then install multiple browser fx IE and firefox and run test  simultanious?

Thanks

Comment: 1. Is it necessary for your application to work in both 32 and 64 bit browsers?
 2. Yes. Grid controls multiple machines with multiple operating systems and multiple browsers, and can run tests simultaneously on all of these.

Comment: Thanks. Yes it should work on both 32 and 64 bit. Just didnt think there where differens

Comment: Considering 64bit IE is rarely used (the default icons on W7+ are all for the 32bit version), 64bit Chrome is only recently public and 64bit Firefox doesn't exist natively (but rather as a port, called Waterfox) I don't see a point. You also cannot run multiple versions of IE on the same machine, thanks Microsoft for that one. The industry accepted workaround for this is to have multiple Windows VM's holding each version, using the Grid to pass tests around for each IE version.

Comment: @Arran please convert your comment to an answer, could not agree more.